# Can I ask a question about the role of engineers in pace-maker design here?

Tags: discussion, scope, acceptable-questions, stackexchange

I want to ask the following question but I am not sure whether or not it would qualify as a valid question:

> What role do system engineers play in the design and implementation of a pace-maker? It would be greatly appreciated if you back up your answers with actual references and/or experiences.

I reviewed the rules for [Engineering Stack Exchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and it seemed that this type of questions can be treated as "subjective" questions.

I felt according to the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) of "good" subjective questions that this question could qualify as a "decent" subjective question.

This question would naturally require the answerer to present "long and not short answers". It asks for "sharing experiences over opinions". I have insisted that their "opinions should be backed with facts and references".

I THINK the tone of this question is "constructive, fair, and impartial".

I do believe this question is MORE THAN "mindless social fun". It is helpful for people who want to learn the design flow for industry-level applications. It will inform the questioner and the readers about the roles of various/specific fields in the design of such applications. This will hopefully inform them about the practicality and relevance of certain/specific career paths in the industry.

Could I ask this question on Engineering Stack Exchange?

Comment: It's also *extremely* broad, in addition to being subjective.

Comment: Thanks to Servy, I NOW know that such a question is too broad to be a part of any Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That question is what we call *too broad*.  One could also argue that it has a element of *opinion based*.  Therefore, do not ask it on the main site.

The exact divisions of responsibility between different types of engineers on a particular project is far from standard, and depends heavily on the specific people that are available.  Even good answers to this question would devolve into splitting hairs between what is systems engineering versus component engineering versus architecture versus ...

Don't do it.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to ask about the **general** design flow of a pace-maker in the industry? I understand that different corporations have varying protocols but I have a feeling that "fundamentally" they should all follow the same procedure.

Comment: @a_sid: No that would be way too broad.